# JQGrid data is not loading with JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, jsp, jqgrid

I am new to jQuery. I have problem while loading data in jQuery grid. I'm having troubles when showing my JSON data in jqGrid.

In my **firstpage.jsp** am printing jQuery grid like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'nybpayments_feeder.jsp?tranType='+tranType,
    mtype:'POST',
    datatype:"json",
    colNames: ['Acctparty', 'Amount', 'Asofdate','Chipref'],

    colModel: [
      { name: 'acctparty', index: 'acctparty', width: 110, align: 'center', sorttype: 'string' },
      { name: 'amount', index: 'bmount',  width: 130, align: 'right', sorttype: 'float'},
      {name: 'asOfDate', index: 'asOfDate', width: 85, sorttype: 'date', align: 'center',datefmt: 'Y-m-d' },
      { name: 'chipref', index: 'chipref', width: 110, align: 'center', sorttype: 'string' },        
    ],

    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5,10, 20, 30,40],
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height:200,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    width:1250,
    loadonce:true,
    caption:"Compressed Billings:"}).navGrid('#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:true})
});
```

The resulting string from the server looks like this:

```
{"total":10,"page":10,"records":10,"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["\/IRELAND",1.5955875E8,"2013-12-30",null]},
                                           {"id":"2","cell":["\/IRELAND",1.3453294479E8,"2013-12-30",null]},{"id":"3","cell":[null,1.1684737776E8,"2013-12-30",null]}
```

In my **secondpage.jsp**, I am printing json string in jsp like this

```
response.setContentType("text/json");
ut.println(string);
```

Comment: How does it display improperly?  Do you get any errors instead of it displaying?

Comment: Thankyou for replay Smith.I am not getting any error in jsp the jquery grid also not diplayed .modified amount filed also:{ name: 'amount', index: 'amount',  width: 130, align: 'right', sorttype: 'float'},.Is there any issue in code .please replay

Comment: Now am able to get the data in jquery grid.please find below change i done:

Comment: Now am able to get the data in jquery grid.please find below change i done:                    
       jsonReader : {
       root: "rows",
        page: "page",
       total: "total",
       records: "records",
       repeatitems: true,
       cell: "cell",
       id: "id",
       userdata: "userdata",
       subgrid: {root:"rows", 
          repeatitems: true, 
          cell:"cell"
       }
     },

Comment: pager: "#pager",
      rowNum: 1,
      rowList: [1,2,3,4,5],
      sortorder: "desc",
      viewrecords: true,
      gridview: true,
      autoencode: true,
      height:200,
      shrinkToFit:false,
       width:5700,
      loadonce:true,
       caption:"Compressed Billings:"                               Thankssss...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `jsonReader` property in the jqgrid. Also the colModel and the json objects don't seem to match.

Comment: Thank for your replay skariya i add JsonReader like this:                  pager: "#pager",
      rowNum: 5,
      rowList: [5,10, 20, 30,40],
      sortorder: "desc",
      viewrecords: true,
      gridview: true,
      autoencode: true,
      height:200,
      shrinkToFit:false,
       width:1250,
      loadonce:true,
       caption:"Compressed Billings:",
        jsonReader : {
        repeatitems: true,
          cell: "cell",
         id:"id",
         userdata: "userdata",
         root: "properties",
         page: "page",
         total: "total",
         records: "records"
       }

Comment: Still data is not getting dispalyed and grid box also not getting displayed .please help me in this i need to change and thing in Json String object return .

Comment: Now am able to get the data in jquery grid.please find below change i done:                    
       jsonReader : {
       root: "rows",
        page: "page",
       total: "total",
       records: "records",
       repeatitems: true,
       cell: "cell",
       id: "id",
       userdata: "userdata",
       subgrid: {root:"rows", 
          repeatitems: true, 
          cell:"cell"
       }
     },

Comment: pager: "#pager",
      rowNum: 1,
      rowList: [1,2,3,4,5],
      sortorder: "desc",
      viewrecords: true,
      gridview: true,
      autoencode: true,
      height:200,
      shrinkToFit:false,
       width:5700,
      loadonce:true,
       caption:"Compressed Billings:"                               Thankssss...